# How do I auto update SALES STATUS for wp e-commerce plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, bitcoin

I am using the Bitpay merchant plugin inside the wp e-commerce plugin (for my Bitcoin store - https://robt.info/bitcoin-store/) to sell downloadable products ONLY and it is working fine...

I am not using any other payment gateways like Paypal or Google Checkout.

The only problem I have is that once a payment has successfully gone through, the user is then sent through to the transactions_results/sessionid page and it says that the payment is pending... WHY?

In the CMS, the transaction appears with a Sales Status of 'INCOMPLETE SALE'. When I manually change this to 'ACCEPTED PAYMENT', everything works fine... the email gets sent and the downloadable products appear in the YOUR DOWNLOADS section of the YOUR ACCOUNT page.

So I guess my question is, how can I have the SALE STATUS of 'INCOMPLETE SALE' automatically update to 'ACCEPTED PAYMENT' once checkout is complete with out me having to do this manually????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by simple changing the HTTP protocol to HTTPS in wordpress...

To do this, go to DASHBOARD > > SETTINGS > > GENERAL > >

Change both the **WordPress Address (URL)** and the **Site Address (URL)** from HTTP to HTTPS

This will allow Bitpay to successfully interact with your sites NotificationURL

Answer (score -1):

Just also mention if you don't have SLL's setup this will take your website offline, as it just did with mine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question; if you want to add contextual information, you should consider editing the answer or adding a comment, once you have enough reputation.